# .call method argument '[' and ']' convention

Tags: javascript

I have following statement

```
.call(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]]);
```

What is `[` and `]`brackets convention in arguments, above statement could be written like this

```
.call(thisArg, arg1, arg2, ...);
```

what is the significance writing `(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])`    instead of `(thisArg, arg1, arg2, ...)`.

Comment: it signifies that they are optional

Comment: Ever heard of `optional parameters`? The `[]` notation is the common notation for optional parameters

Comment: @MatthewMcveigh should it be like .call(thisArg[, arg1, arg2, ...]);

Comment: @ozil no, having the nested brackets implies that you can have an optional number of parameters after `thisArg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments inside `[` and `]` are optional. Also notice that `,` is also in the `[]`. So, if you want to add a parameter to `call` you should prefix it with `,`.

So, you can call `call` as follow:

```
.call(thisArg); // Without params

.call(thisArg, arg1); // With one param


.call(thisArg, arg1, arg2);
```

and so on.

Comment: should it be like  `.call(thisArg[, arg1, arg2, ...]); `

Comment: @ozil See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: the confusion is with brackets it look like they are nested `(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])`

Comment: @ozil No, this means that each one parameter inside `[]` is optional and `[]` should not be used in syntax